# When I load data from my database I want to create multiple pins on my map, now I only get 1 pin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps, pins

I am working with a map in xamarin forms and came across a problem that I cannot seem to solve.
I want to add multiple pins (to multiple locations) and in my database in parse I have data for 3 different places but when I test it on the app only 1 pin appear on the map.

This is my code:

```
var getItems = await parseAPI.getInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString ()); //I load my data.

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {
    mLong = currentItem ["long"].ToString (); //my long from my data
    mLat = currentItem ["lat"].ToString (); //my lat from my data

}

var storeLong = Double.Parse (mLong, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //converting the long from string to int.
var storeLat = Double.Parse (mLat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //converting the lat from string to int.

if (mLong != null) {

    var pin = new Pin ();
    pin.Position = new Position (storeLat,storeLng); //here i add the data i have.
    pin.Label = "test";
    pin.Address = "test";

    theMap.Pins.Add (pin); //adding my pins to my map. 
}
```

Maybe I need to create a `list <String>` somehow?

Comment: you need to put the logic to create the pin INSIDE the foreach loop

Comment: that did it! haha it wasnt harder than that! thanks jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a pin for each of the `getItems`, only the last one, try extending for `foreach` to wrap the entire code snippet:

```
var getItems = await parseAPI.getInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["sessionToken"].ToString ()); //I load my data.

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) 
{
    mLong = currentItem ["long"].ToString (); //my long from my data
    mLat = currentItem ["lat"].ToString (); //my lat from my data

    var storeLong = Double.Parse (mLong, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //converting the long from string to int.
    var storeLat = Double.Parse (mLat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //converting the lat from string to int.

    if (mLong != null) 
    {
        var ourPosition = new Position (13, -15);
        theMap.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
        theMap.MoveToRegion (
            MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (
                ourPosition, Distance.FromMeters (300)));

        var pin = new Pin ();
        pin.Position = new Position (storeLat,storeLng); //here i add the data i have.
        pin.Label = "test";
        pin.Address = "test";
        pin.Clicked += onButtonClicked1;

        theMap.Pins.Add (pin); //adding my pins to my map. 
    }
}
```